# how can i increase my pdf size working with jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Hello senior developers and programmers,

I am working with a script, that is integrated with jspdf,
basically the script is supposed to convert my website content to pdf,
There are two types of concept to this scripts.

the selectable and canvas,
the canvas been for complex webpages, e.g tables, spaces, background images.

it works successfully but my pdf is not to clear and just stays in the middle

this is the javascript code

```
//Download as a canvas if contains complex data
    $('.wppdf-download-canvas').click(function() {  
        var pdfname = $(this).attr('name');             
        var htmlSource = $(this).siblings('.wppdf');    
        var canvasToImage = function(canvas){
            var img = new Image();
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            img.src = dataURL;
            return img;
        };
        var canvasShiftImage = function(oldCanvas,shiftAmt){
            shiftAmt = parseInt(shiftAmt, 10) || 0;
            if(!shiftAmt){ return oldCanvas; }

            var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height - shiftAmt;
            newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
            var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

            var img = canvasToImage(oldCanvas);
            ctx.drawImage(img,0, shiftAmt, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

            return newCanvas;
        };

        var canvasToImageSuccess = function(canvas){
            var pdf = new jsPDF2('p','pt'),
                pdfInternals = pdf.internal,
                pdfPageSize = pdfInternals.pageSize,
                pdfScaleFactor = pdfInternals.scaleFactor,
                pdfPageWidth = pdfPageSize.width,
                pdfPageHeight = pdfPageSize.height,
                totalPdfHeight = 0,
                htmlPageHeight = canvas.height,
                htmlScaleFactor = canvas.width / (pdfPageWidth * pdfScaleFactor),
                safetyNet = 0;

            while(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight && safetyNet < 15){
                var newCanvas = canvasShiftImage(canvas, totalPdfHeight);
                pdf.addImage(newCanvas, 'png', 15, 15, pdfPageWidth - (pdfPageWidth * .0 ), 0, null, 'NONE');

                totalPdfHeight += (pdfPageHeight * pdfScaleFactor * htmlScaleFactor);

                safetyNet++;
            }

            pdf.save(pdfname);
        };
```

i tried changing the size using this var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

because i wanted it bigger, but nothing happns when i try to download my page.

Any advice

Answer (score 1):

so i got this, with a little bit of research online
pdf.addImage(newCanvas, 'png', -120, 10, 700, 580);

and that solved the problem.